# Laravel the modal popup is not working with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal

Hello guys i was trying to make a modal popup using ajax in my laravel project but it's not working,
i tried to make an alert popup and it was working so fine but the modal is not and this is my code

The error is  $(...).modal is not a function

```
<div class="content">
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="edit_click btn btn-warning" >Edit</a>

</div>

<script>

    $(function (){
            $('.edit_click').click(function (){

            $('#editModal').modal('show');


            });
        });

</script>
```

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your code. what is wrong? :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="content">
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Hello World
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="edit_click btn btn-warning" >Edit</a>

</div>

<script>

    $(function (){
            $('.edit_click').click(function (){

            $('#editModal').modal('show');


            });
        });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/socb29ea/

Comment: Yes now i got it worked .. when you put it this way it worked so i realized that it was because of the included scripts in the layout there was this thing i don't know what it does ($.noConflict();) and when i removed it from the code it worked,  so thanks a lot